# servlet not able to read image from http server

Tags: java, image, tomcat, servlets

I have an image coming from remote server through http url. I want to do some image analysis on this, so I want to read the image content in my server side java code. This code is running inside the tomcat server.

```
    public ImageTrimmer(String urlPath) {
        imageSrc = urlPath;
        try {
           Image img = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageSrc));  // throws the exception
            img.getRGB(0, 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Problem reading image", e );
        }
    }
```

The url for image can be any valid url that returns image. An example url path is - "http://build.ford.com/dig/Ford/E-Series Cargo Van/2012/BP3TT-FULL-EXT/Image[|Ford|E-Series Cargo Van|2012|1|1.|.E1E..YZ...89E.BS1.CB1.]/EXT/1/vehicle.png".

Here is the exception I get while reading the image

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://build.ford.com/dig/Ford/E-Series Cargo Van/2012/BP3TT-FULL-EXT/Image[|Ford|E-Series Cargo Van|2012|1|1.|.E1E..YZ...89E.BS1.CB1.]/EXT/1/vehicle.png

        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1367)
```

Any help to read this image successfully will be veryhelpful.

Comment: the code in the try block, have you check if it is compile-able? my eclipse give error with that code of yours. I have a compilable code with a few changes and it get the image's width and height correctly. If you want, I can paste the code as answer.

Answer (score 0):

When typing in browser, the browser help u do some work. In order to access it, try encode the url in you code(to escape some specific character like / ,blank) first. One optional API is,

URLEncoder.encode(arg0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here there is no argument for URL. This URLEncoder does not help. Please see my reply to above comment. Could you please help resolving this.

Comment: @Ashok , I don't see you use encode API here, do u follow the code michael given?
ImageIO.read(new URL(encodedPathURL))
when encode the url, it will only handle the non-ascii character

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Tomcat is choking on the whitespace in the URL. Try encoding the String urlPath to something Tomcat can understand.

```
String encodedPathURL;
try
{
  encodedPathURL = java.net.URLEncoder().encode(urlPath, "UTF-8");
}
catch(UnsupportedEncodingException exception)
{
  //Exception handling here
}
```

and using the properly encoded String encodedPathURL when calling ImageIO.read(new URL(encodedPathURL)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The URLEncoder does not work. It encodes http:// as well. I tried something as follows, even this does not work. Can you please suggest a correct way to fis this.              URI url = new URI("http", host, path);
                img = ImageIO.read(url.toURL());